# Unexpected char when executing .ps1 file using PuTTY Plink

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, putty, plink

I'm executing remotely some scripts to get information from a server, using Plink tool from putty. The trouble comes when I use a .ps1 file, because one '?' appears on the beginning, making the first line incorrect, but with .bat files works as desired.

For example, I want to print the content of a file:

**GetDate.bat:**

```
type C:/Data/DateOfCompilation.txt
```

And then:

```
PS C:/Users/MyUser> plink -ssh <User>@<IP> -i C:\Key.ppk -m C:\Scripts\GetDate.bat
10/09/2018 14:32:02,72
```

Everything okay

**GetDate.ps1:**

```
Get-Content -Path C:/Data/DateOfCompilation.txt
```

Execution:

```
PS C:/Users/MyUser> plink -ssh <User>@<IP> -i C:\Key.ppk -m C:\Scripts\GetDate.ps1

?Get-Content : The term '?Get-Content' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again. At line:1 char:1 

+ ?Get-Content -Path C:/Data/DateOfCompilation.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (?Get-Content:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Also, if I add more code, the other lines work fine, it's just the first one which fails with that **'?'** added at the beginning.

(However, running locally the script works fine)

I have other ps1 scripts much more extended, so using only bat files is not the best option.

I have looked at the documentation, other forums and here, but I'm not able to find anything. Maybe I do not know anything about ps1 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there's UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of `GetDate.ps1` - If there is, remove it.

---

Though the root cause your problem may be your misunderstanding of that `-m` switch of Plink does. It makes Plink read the file and send its contents (and only the contents) to the server. The server never learns, what the file extension is. So it makes no sense to use .ps vs .bat. No matter, what the extension is, the file will be interpreted by the default shell of your Windows SSH server. What is PowerShell (according to the error message).

So even your `type` command in .bat file was executed by PowerShell, not by `cmd.exe`. In PowerShell, `type` is an alias to `Get-Content`.

The reason why your .bat file works is most probably that it has no BOM, while your .ps1 has BOM. Had you executed your .ps1 with PowerShell, it would handle the BOM correctly. But you are not executing .ps1 with PowerShell, you are executing its contents, and in that case the BOM probably causes problems.

The difference is basically like between:

```
powershell.exe -File GetDate.ps1
```

and

```
powershell.exe < GetDate.ps1
```

Both do basically the same, but the latter fails with BOM, while the first handles it correctly.

Comment: So true! I checked the hex code of the file and started with EF BB BF (BOM you said). However creating a ps1 with notepad doesn't have BOM and works, probably PowerShell ISE adds it when you create a file. Thank you so much!